# Which web technologies are available for displaying vector map in Polymer?

Tags: maps, polymer, leaflet, vector-graphics, jvectormap

I am working on my first web project, so newbie here. I use **Polymer 1.0**, and I want to display an *imaginary* map.

This map was designed with Illustrator, and therefore I can export the map in `.pdf` or `.svg`.

Which tools would let me to use this map and navigate through it, add some markers, etc... using **Polymer**?

I am currently trying to make *Leaflet* and *JVectorMap* working, but I am lacking experience with web technologies and I don't even know if these tools will allow me to do what I've explained above. All the examples I found so far are real-world maps.

Comment: SVG should work with Polymer. PDF not so much.

Comment: I can't make much sense of your question but SVG is supported in the browser and by Polymer  without any additional tools.

Comment: I want to use some navigation tools on a vectorized (svg e.g.) map in a Polymer environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool I've found for tying data to an SVG and making it interactive is [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). Here's [a simple example](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2322933) that builds the SVG from JSON data, but you could skip that step and use an existing SVG. Once you're comfortable with that, have a look at the [examples gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) to see other ways you can use d3.js to interact with your map.